# How to Hide Menu Items in WordPress After Creating Pages with Shortcodes?

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-insert-post, menu-item-hide

I'm currently working on a WordPress plugin development project in PHP, where I've created several shortcodes to implement different functionalities, like a login page, an unauthorized page, and a dashboard. To navigate to these functionalities, I've created pages with the corresponding shortcodes.

I've successfully created these pages using the following code in my activation hook:

```
function my_plugin_activation() {
    $pageData = array(
        'post_title' => 'Dashboard',
        'post_content' => '[dashboard]', // shortcode
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_name' => 'dashboard',
    );

    // Insert the new page
    $pageId = wp_insert_post($pageData);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activation');
```

As a result, after activating the plugin, WordPress automatically adds these pages to the header menu. However, I would like to achieve two specific goals:

- Hide the menu items for "Dashboard" and "Unauthorized" pages.
- Hide the pre-login menus and show only menu items which is associated with post-login functionalities, which might include "Dashboard," "Profile," and "Logout."

Could someone provide code-level solutions to achieve these objectives within the plugin's activation block, ensuring that these changes work automatically for anyone using the plugin?

**Before Plugin Activation:**

[image]

**After Plugin Activation:**

[image]

I have tried following code, but nothing works

**Approach #1:**

```
// If the page should not be linked to any menu
// Remove it from the default header menu
$menu_name = 'twentytwentytwo'; // Replace with the name of your menu
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($menu_name);

if ($menu) {
    $menu_id = $menu->term_id;
                    
    // Find and remove the page from the default menu
    $menuItems = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu_id);
    foreach ($menuItems as $menuItem) {
        if ($menuItem->object_id == $pageId) {
            wp_delete_post($menuItem->ID);
        }
    }
}
```

Approach #2:

```
function my_plugin_activation() {
    $pageData = array(
        'post_title' => 'Dashboard',
        'post_content' => '[dashboard]', // shortcode
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_name' => 'dashboard',
    );

    // Insert the new page
    $pageId = wp_insert_post($pageData);

    // Register a function to modify the menu items
    add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_remove_menu_items');
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activation');


function my_remove_menu_items($items) {
    // Menu item slugs to be removed
    $menu_item_slugs = array('dashboard'); // Replace with actual slugs
    
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        if (in_array($item->post_name, $menu_item_slugs)) {
            unset($items[$key]);
        }
    }
    
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: You might be assuming the WordPress administrator will use a "List of Pages" menu. You say: *WordPress automatically adds these pages to the header menu.* This is only true if the administrator configures their menu to do so. There are many options for building menus available to the administrator/developer that can circumvent the idea to hide/show pages generated by your plugin. Changes in the technical implementation of navigation between versions before 5.9 and after make this even more difficult. It is possible to achieve your goal only within a limited range of WordPress configurations.

Comment: In the context of my previous comment, the concept (not the details) in the answer by Lucas Brown makes sense. Lucas's concept does not hide the option from the menu. It conditionally hides content (and/or displays alternative content) that would be displayed for a non-logged in user. This is something that as the plugin developer you can control. You can't control how the WordPress administrator creates their menus. This wouldn't be an issue if you were designing the plugin for yourself alone. But, as a plugin for use by anyone there are limits with what you can control.

Comment: @kofeigen - I am developing for the wide range of customers. So need to show the respective menu items in the header menu bar. Currently I am using wordpress v 6.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer!

In WordPress, the `post_status` field is used to define the current status of a post or page.

**Private (`private`):**

- Purpose: Represents a post or page that is private and not visible to
  the public.
- Menu Item: Doesn't add a menu item.

So, using this option we can solve the scenario which is explained in the question.

**Resultant Code:**

```
function my_plugin_activation() {
    $pageData = array(
        'post_title' => 'Dashboard',
        'post_content' => '[dashboard]', // shortcode
        'post_status' => 'private',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_name' => 'dashboard',
    );

    // Insert the new page
    $pageId = wp_insert_post($pageData);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activation');
```

In respective to Post login menus I created a custom template layout for those pages.

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer? In WordPress version 6.2.3 with Twenty Twenty-Three theme, a default navigation block does not display menu options for private pages--even for Administrators. When you say you created a *custom template layout*, was a custom menu created as well? Or did you make the Dashboard, Profile and Logout options available outside of a menu? By default private pages are only visible to Administrators and Editors. So, to solve the scenario in the question, wouldn't you need to programmatically add menu options for private pages so they appear for logged in users?

Answer (score -3):

To hide menu items in WordPress after creating pages with shortcodes, follow this succinct strategy:

Create a Page with Shortcode: First, create the pages you want to display in your menu, each with the corresponding shortcode. Shortcodes are typically used to embed dynamic content, so these pages may not need to be directly accessible from the menu.

Access the Menu Editor:

Navigate to your WordPress dashboard.
Go to "Appearance" and select "Menus."
Add Custom Link:

In the Menu Editor, click "Custom Links" on the left.
In the URL field, add a "#" symbol. This creates a placeholder link.
In the Link Text field, enter the name you want for the menu item (e.g., "Hidden Page").
Click the "Add to Menu" button.
Organize the Menu:

Rearrange your menu items as needed.
To make the "Hidden Page" a child item of a visible menu item, drag it slightly to the right beneath the parent item.
Save the Menu:

Don't forget to save your menu.
Modify Shortcode Visibility:

If you want to make the hidden pages accessible through the shortcode, you can modify the shortcode's behavior to display the content conditionally. For example, you can use a plugin like "Conditional Blocks" or add PHP conditions to your shortcode to determine when the content should be visible.
By following these steps, you can effectively hide menu items in WordPress while still being able to access the corresponding pages via shortcodes or other conditional display methods.

Comment: Could you provide code-level solutions to achieve these objectives within the plugin's activation block, ensuring that these changes work automatically for anyone using the plugin?